# DCC GARCH in R: Number of Observations

Tags: r

I am running a DCC GARCH model in R. The codes are attached below.

```
dfm3dr<-data.frame(lnm3dr,lnreer)

ug_spec<-ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(0,0)), variance.model = 
list(model="sGARCH",garchOrder=c(1,1)), distribution.model = "sstd")
ugm3dr<-ugarchfit(spec=ug_spec,data=dfm3dr$lnm3dr)
ugm3dreer<-ugarchfit(spec=ug_spec,data=dfm3dr$lnreer)


uspec.m3dr<-multispec(replicate(2,ugarchspec(mean.model = 
list(armaOrder=c(0,0)), variance.model = 
list(model="sGARCH",garchOrder=c(1,1)))))
multif.m3dr<-multifit(uspec.m3dr,dfm3dr)

specm3dr<-dccspec(uspec = uspec.m3dr, robust=TRUE, lag.criterion="SC", 
model="DCC",dccOrder = c(1,1),distribution =  "mvnorm")
fitm3dr<-dccfit(specm3dr,data=dfm3dr, solver="lbfgs", fit.control = 
list(eval.se=TRUE), fit=multif.m3dr)

covm3dr_1<-rcov(fitm3dr)
corm3dr_1<-rcor(fitm3dr)
cor_m3dr__reer<-corm3dr_1[2,1,]
cor_lnm3d__lnreer<-ts(data=cor_m3d__reer, start = 1994, frequency = 4,end = 
2017, deltat = 1/12)

plot(cor_lnm3d__lnreer)
```

The codes are running perfectly for 200 observations. But when I run them for less than 100 observations, I face the following errors

```
  ugm3dr<-ugarchfit(spec=ug_spec,data=dfm3dr$lnm3dr)
 **Warning message:
  In .sgarchfit(spec = spec, data = data, out.sample = out.sample,  : 
  ugarchfit-->waring: using less than 100 data
  points for estimation**


Warning messages:
 1: In .sgarchfit(spec = spec, data = data, out.sample = out.sample,  : 
ugarchfit-->waring: using less than 100 data
 points for estimation

2: In .sgarchfit(spec = spec, data = data, out.sample = out.sample,  : 
ugarchfit-->waring: using less than 100 data
points for estimation
```

Error in .dccfit(spec = spec, data = data, out.sample = out.sample, solver = solver,  :

dccfit-->error: function requires at least 100 data
 points to run

I would like to know how can I tackle this issue of limited availability of data points. 
Thanks in advance,

Prashant

Comment: That kind of models need a bigger sample because the number of estimated parameters is also big

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Robert. So do you suggest me to shift to some other method like Time varying VAR to analyze dynamic correlations?

Comment: Or increase your sample using more frequent data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.